# Trying to understand JOINS and when to use them in a homework problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and I am not sure if I am using conditions correctly for a question I am trying to answer for homework.

I have a full on SELECT statement, I just would like to know if I am using the conditions correctly, if the code is correct at all. I am not able to test it as I was not given the table contents.

The question I am trying to answer is: Produce a result set showing department name, employee first name, employee last name, employee title, and employee hourly wage. Include only records that satisfy both of two conditions: employees with an hourly wage of $25 or more; and employees with ‘Analyst’ anywhere in their title. Sort by department name and then by employee title.

Here is the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyvhb.jpg

```
SELECT deptName, empFirstName, empLastName, empTitle, empHourlyWage
FROM department, employee
JOIN employee on department.deptID=employee.deptID
WHERE empHourlyWage >= 25.00
AND empTitle LIKE ‘%Analyst’ 
ORDER BY deptName, empTitle;
```

I don't think I used JOIN correctly, just wanting to know the correct way to complete this question.

Comment: So is JOIN not necessary?

Comment: Remove " , employee " out of the FROM clause

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but put a % after your '%Analyst' statement as well. The question reads "'Analyst' anywhere in their title".  Using '%Analyst' will only work if the title ENDS in Analyst.  You should say  AND empTitle LIKE '%Analyst%'

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing old-style "joins in the FROM clause" (pre-ANSI) joins and ANSI-style joins. To quote Pink Floyd, "This will not do". :-)

Just drop the ", employee" from the FROM clause and I think you're good:

```
SELECT deptName, empFirstName, empLastName, empTitle, empHourlyWage
FROM department
JOIN employee on department.deptID=employee.deptID
WHERE empHourlyWage >= 25.00
AND empTitle LIKE ‘%Analyst’ 
ORDER BY deptName, empTitle;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query will generally look more or less like this:

```
SELECT <columns and expressions of what you want to know>
FROM   <a table>
INNER JOIN <another table>
        ON <clause that relates first table to this table>
WHERE <zero or more predicates to filter on>
ORDER BY <columns to sort by>
```

So in your `FROM` clause, just take out `employee`.

There is an older, non-ANSI syntax that is specific to Oracle that puts a comma separated list of tables in the `FROM` clause and does not use the `JOIN` keyword. I'd suggest you not use it, but if you did, your query would look like:

```
SELECT deptName, empFirstName, empLastName, empTitle, empHourlyWage
  FROM department, employee
 WHERE department.deptID=employee.deptID  [<-- JOIN condition is here]
   AND empHourlyWage >= 25.00
   AND empTitle LIKE '%Analyst'
 ORDER BY deptName, empTitle;
```

Also, watch out for the curly quotes in your `empHourlyWage` clause.

Comment: In your second example, did you mean to have both the old-style and new-style joins in there? ???

Comment: Oops, no. Fixed.